# Gerrit doesnt show new commits

Tags: git, gerrit

I set up a Gerrit Server on Ubuntu 14.04 with HTTP-Authentication. Git is working fine with it so far, I also included a hook for change IDs so that nothing should go wrong. I can work with git without problems, clone repos and push commits to gerrit. But I have a problem with gerrit itself, because it does not show the changes I made, my test-ptoject is just empty. I also checked the files on the server and it loks like they get changed every time I push a commit (Timestamps of the packs are the same as my push), so the new or changed files seem to be there.

Comment: What push command are you using? Are you pushing to `refs/for/<branch>`? Do you know, how a workflow with Gerrit is meant to be? Have you checked the web interface, is your commit shown there as proposed change? Please check the [User Guide](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.11.2/intro-user.html)

Comment: maybe you did "git push" directly to your gerrit branch. if you use git push ...HEAD:refs/for/ur branch.then you can see your change in browser - (open status)

Comment: I know how gerrit works and what it is used for, I've been using it for a while now, just never set up my own server. as push command i use: git push <address> HEAD:refs/for/master

Comment: Do you have access to the project? Are you logging into the web page with the correct credentials?